# PHP8: Increasing unset indexes elegantly and fast

Tags: php, indexing, null, php-8

PHP8 triggers a warning if an index in not set.

In PHP7 the following (very simplified) snippet used to be a 'dirty' but a very readable and working solution to count stuff according to their key on the fly (eg in re-indexing algorithms):

```
$keylist = array('keyA','keyB','keyA','keyA');
$idx_count = array();
foreach ($keylist as $thiskey){
    $idx_count[$thiskey]++;
}
```

Solutions in PHP8 to require to check for existence of the index as in a check with isset():

```
$keylist = array('keyA','keyB','keyA','keyA');
$idx_count = array();
foreach ($keylist as $thiskey){
    if (!isset($idx_count[$thiskey]){ $idx_count[$thiskey] = 0; }
    $idx_count[$thiskey]++;
}
```

or a check with empty():

```
$keylist = array('keyA','keyB','keyA','keyA');
$idx_count = array();
foreach ($keylist as $thiskey){
    if (empty($idx_count[$thiskey]){ $idx_count[$thiskey] = 0; }
    $idx_count[$thiskey]++;
}
```

or with branching:

```
$keylist = array('keyA','keyB','keyA','keyA');
$idx_count = array();
foreach ($keylist as $thiskey){
    if (!isset($idx_count[$thiskey]){
        $idx_count[$thiskey] = 1;
    }else{
        $idx_count[$thiskey]++;
    }
}
```

or using a null coalescing op:

```
$keylist = array('keyA','keyB','keyA','keyA');
$idx_count = array();
foreach ($keylist as $thiskey){
    $idx_count[$thiskey] ??= 0;
    $idx_count[$thiskey]++;
}
```

Questions:
1. Besides cluttering readability, how do these options impact the performance with very large $keylists?
In either case, it's an extra comparison on every loop, while the internal 'catch' in PHP7 (probably) only impacted the first iteration.

2. Is there an elegant way to make this readable and fast at the same time?

Comment: _"how does do these options impact the performance with very large $keylists?"_ - Why don't you test it with a dataset that's equally as large and see if you notice any difference and is worth the time trying to improve it?

Comment: Does `array_count_values($keylist)` count?

Comment: I'm almost positive that the performance impact of checking the keys in any of these ways will be nigh-unmeasurable. On the other hand "elegant" is highly subjective, but should also be one of the last things to consider when writing code, coming after "functional", "readable", and "maintainable". IMO a lot of code described primarily with subjective terms like "elegant" and "clever" tend to score low on readability/maintainability and/or leverage language quirks like "PHP<=7 doesn't complain very loudly about unset keys" that have a habit of not surviving language version increments unscathed

Comment: in the tests i made, the effects were hard to measure. someone else might have more insigths. array_count_values is not iterative and cant be used if the process involves multiple datasets.

Comment: Please chose code-readability over micro-optimization!

Answer (score 0):

I know people hate the error-suppression operator, but you could use

```
@$idx_count[$thiskey]++;
```

Another option is to prefill the array with all the required keys before the loop.

```
$idx_count = array_fill_keys($keylist, 0);
```

Comment: both valid points. but let's assume we don't want to suppress errors. and array_fill_keys() would only work if the index is not aggregating in let say multiple passes over different lists.

Comment: You seem to be making an assumption that the PHP designers want to make what you're doing as easy as it used to be. I think they've deliberately made it harder.